# React native pass route.params to fetch request

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation

I using the `this.props.navigation.navigate('Details',{activity: item})` to pass the item to a new page. And i want to make a fetch request by using this activity. I cannot get how to pass the item to the API request. Anyone can answer me?

```
register = async () =>{
        var token = await AsyncStorage.getItem('id_token')
        console.log(token)
        fetch('http://192.168.0.1:8887/api/auth/activities/register',{
            method: 'POST',
            headers:{
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Authorization': 'Bearer ' +token,
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({

            })

        })
    }
render(){
   const { activity } = this.props.route.params;
    return (  

       <View style={styles.container}>
          <ScrollView style={styles.content}>
             <Text style={styles.data}>Title:</Text>
             <Text style={styles.info}>{activity.name}</Text>
          </ScrollView>
             <Button title="register" onPress={this.register}></Button>
       </View>
      )
    }
```

In this case, how can i pass the data to the fetch?

Comment: ```constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            activity : this.props.route.params,
        }
    };``` this way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All other answers suggesting you should add it to your state are wrong. You can retrieve the value just like you're already doing in your `render` function.

```js
register = async () =>{
    const { activity } = this.props.route.params;
    const token = await AsyncStorage.getItem('id_token')

    fetch('http://192.168.0.125:8887/api/auth/activities/register',{
        method: 'POST',
        headers:{
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' +token,
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({ activity })
    });
}
```